# Can't read my STM32 WL55JC1 on the STM32Cube Programmer

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

Before this I'm launching my modified version of LoRaWAN_End_Node firmware, but my Nucleo Board keeps restarting and heating up so I unplugged the USB cable. When I tried to connect my board back I get a `FAILS.txt` file with the following content

```
The interface firmware FAILED to reset/halt the target MCU
```

I tried to connect my MCU to the STM32Cube Programmer with under reset configuration and trying all reset mode configuration but got no luck.

Other things that I've tried:

1. Disconnect JP1
2. Connecting while pushing the reset button
3. Doing point 1 and 2 at the same time

And still got no luck.

[image]

**UPDATE #1**

1. Replugged the JP1 jumper and the heating issue is back (The MCU
   isn't completely dead, I guess (?))
2. It is a Nucleo Board so it should be using an official ST-LINK

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your microcontroller is in fact dead. If there is a problem with your board heating excessively and it cant read/write data then there is definitely a short somewhere. My best guess would be either the interface chip (connects your usb to the microcontroller) or the MCU itself is shorted. If you have a multimeter and a lot of time or a thermal camera you can see what is shorted. You might just want to buy a new development board instead, as that would save a lot of time (The nucleo is an interface that will let you easily program a MCU, not the MCU itself. It includes a crystal oscillator as well as the aforementioned interface chip along with regulators and such)

Comment: Well, the worst case is happening then. Thought it was because a minor software bug since I'm new in STM32 and the heating issue is gone because it only happens if I use the LoRaWAN.

Tried on a different board and the heating issue is gone with LoRaWAN program flashed. Guess the LoRa chip was defective and somehow damaged the MCU chip.

Comment: Anyway, are there any tip(s) to prevent this kind of thing happens (from software side since I use the Nucleo board)? I don't wanna fried the spare board since it's kinda expensive lol.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem on the software side, It is probably a defective part.